# Gui is messed up while editing a file in vim

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04

[image]
I am having a weird problem with vim, using Ubuntu 14.04.
Mysteriously, when i edit a file in vim, it starts to mess up all the GUI, and my terminal looks like that, and its not just the terminal, it happens in my desktop as well, i tried to switch my terminal, but it did seem to solve the problem.
any clue guys ?

Comment: it doesn't look like a problem with vim

Comment: What part of the GUI is messed up?

Comment: I'm slightly suspecting an encoding issue. Does it do the same thing starting vim with `vim -N -U NONE -i NONE`?

Comment: I ended up updating my NVIDIA Video card, i think it helped because it hasn't happened since then :)